# Как получить объект к которому добавлен компонент?

Tags: unity3d

Задача такая есть скрипт который я повесил на камеру, у камеры есть target  объект типа Transform за которым она следит. Как мне вычислить расстояние от камеры до объекта и передвинуть камеру если расстояние больше допустимого значения.

Как получить хотя бы позицию объекта к которому добавлен компонент?

А все разобрался оказыватся тут тоже есть this =)

```
 public class MainCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform Target;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(Target.position, transform.position));
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            transform.LookAt(Target);
            Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(Target.position, transform.position));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, у любого класса, наследующегося от MonoBehaviour есть поле gameObject из которого можно получить объект, на котором сейчас висит данный компонент.
Навскидку по "преследованию":

```
public class cam: MonoBehaviour {
    public float smooth = 0.1f;
    public GameObject target;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, smooth);
    }
}
```

Ну или, например, сделайте камеру дочерним объектом преследуемого объекта она у вас вместе с ним будет менять трансформацию.

Comment: А чтобы по Y  не менялась высота то присваивать текущую высоту? и я использовал вместо лерп какую то более плавную функцию

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, ну, способов то масса) не знаю, что там у вас за реализация используется. Как вариант, да, просто присваивать высоту ту же, что и сейчас.